# I want to call a function inside a const with React, but React is not correctly show the function

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a function within a constant in my child component. The problem I have is that React shows me the desired button, but also the plain code. See image:

[image]

My const:

```
export default function MainComponent() {
const [bildUpload, setBildUpload] = React.useState(false);

const Uping = () => {
return (
  <>
    bildUpload ? (
    <Loading />) : (
    <>
      <input
        accept="image/*"
        name="foto"
        className={classes.input}
        id="contained-button-file"
        onChange={(e) => handleInputChangeBild(e)}
        type="file"
      />
      <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
    </>
    );
  </>
 );
};
[...]
 );
```

}

Here is my child component:

```
<Plan attribute={attribut} Upload={Uping}></Plan>
```

And here i want to call the function correctly:

```
export default function RecipeReviewCard({ attribute, Upload }) {
[...]

return (
<Card>
  <Upload></Upload>
 [...]
  );
}
```

Comment: As `bildUpload` is a JS expression, it always need to be wrapped into curly braces `{bildUpload}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap expressions in curly braces:

```js
return (
  <>
    {bildUpload ? (
    <Loading />) : ( ... )}
  </>
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content you want to render into {} like mentioned in the above response.
Explanation:
Your return tries to interpret the code between <> and </> As HTML, but you want your expression result (result of the ternary) to be evaluated as HTML.